# How to close application by reference?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've two projects in the same solution: `Project (A)` and `Project (B)`.

I've imported the `Project (A)` in the `Project (B)`, so essentially I can manage `A` from `B`. Now when I close the window of project `B` that represents the main project I need to close also the window of project `A`.

In the project `B` when the `OnClosed` event is fired I execute this:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

the problem's that the project `B` remain opened. How can I solve this without creating any instance of the project `A` inside `B`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they both executable projects (WinForms client, WPF, Console app)?  You can't expect one executable to close the other one...they're separate executables.  Can you describe more about what you're doing?  Can you show the relevant code for where you create the instances of each?

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer to this depends on how B created/is managing A

Comment: @rory.ap yes both are two wpf application, sorry I forgot to mention in my question. Anyway all depends on B project

Comment: System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over running processes and close the process by name.

```
    var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach(var process in processes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
        if(process.ProcessName == "NameOfProcessToClose")
        {
            process.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
```

There are also other inter-process mechanisms you can use.
Establish a IP-socket, Named pipe, or a file share to communicate a shutdown to the other process.

Comment: Yes, I was about to mention mutex, but I didnt remember if mutex'es could throw events or if the "receiver" needs to poll the mutex

Comment: No other way to achieve this?

Comment: You also have the power button :)

Comment: I think you need to use inter-process call mechanisms as mentioned. Maybe the Process class is the simplest way to do it

Comment: for example using in the project A inside a static function `Window.Close()` will solve the problem but the method is not static :\

Comment: Why don't you move the windows to two separate WPF User Control Library projects and then reference both these projects and open the windows from within the same running process?

Comment: Check my answer, this will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use CrossAppDomainDelegates to execute code remotely in another application.
 Here's an example to get you started:

```
namespace ApplicationB
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private SecondaryAppHelper _secondaryApp;

        protected override void OnStartup ( StartupEventArgs e )
        {
            _secondaryApp = new SecondaryAppHelper ( );
        }

        protected override void OnExit ( ExitEventArgs e )
        {
            _secondaryApp.Dispose ( );
        }
    }

    sealed class SecondaryAppHelper : IDisposable
    {
        private const string _secondaryDomainName = "ApplicationA Domain";
        private AppDomain _domain;

        public SecondaryAppHelper ( )
        {
            var setup = new AppDomainSetup ( ) { ApplicationBase    = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                                                 ConfigurationFile  = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile, // Here we share the same app.config
                                                 ApplicationName    = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName,
                                                 LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost };

            _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain ( _secondaryDomainName, null, setup );

            // Let's ask our new domain to launch ApplicationA
            // Without creating a new domain, the two WPF windows would share the same render thread.
            _domain.DoCallBack ( ( ) =>
                {
                    var thread = new Thread ( ( ) =>
                    {
                        var app = new ApplicationA.App ( );
                        var win = new ApplicationA.MainWindow ( );

                        app.MainWindow = win;

                        app.Startup += ( sender, e ) => { (sender as ApplicationA.App).MainWindow.Show ( ); };
                        app.Run ( );
                    } );

                    thread.SetApartmentState ( ApartmentState.STA ); // Necessary for WPF & WinForms
                    thread.IsBackground = true; // The thread will terminate itself nicely after the app closes
                    thread.Start ( );
                } );
        }

        public void Dispose ( )
        {
            _domain.DoCallBack ( ( ) =>
                {
                    if ( Application.Current != null )
                    {
                        EventHandler handler = null;

                        handler = ( sender, e ) =>
                            {
                                var dispatcher = sender as Dispatcher;
                                dispatcher.ShutdownFinished -= handler;  // Better safe than sorry

                                 AppDomain.Unload ( AppDomain.CurrentDomain );
                            };

                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.ShutdownFinished += handler;

                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown ( DispatcherPriority.Background );
                    }
                } );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple:

1) In project (b) right click on references and click on add reference

2) Select the project (a) inside projects

3) At this point we need to create an instance of project A inside B, so:

```
public static ProjectA.MainWindow projectA;
```

4) At this point where you need to open the application of project A, for example when you click a menuitem:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    projectA = new ProjectA.MainWindow();
}
```

this will open the projectA, so for close this instead we need to create a method in the projectA:

```
public void Exit()
{
    Close(); //Implicit declaration of Window.Close();
}
```

so in project B:

```
projectA.Exit();
```

will shutdown the whole application. How you can see is useless in this case use the Mutex class or a lot of code for achieve this simple task.

Hope that help..

Comment: `new ProjectA.MainWindow().Exit()` does not exit an already-running instance of ProjectA, which you wanted to do according to your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster read better my answer, the code that I wrote do exactly what I need to do. Try it your self instead of lost your time to put downvote ;)